# Does this symmetrization operator have a name? Any theory?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, terminology

Consider a function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $n$ complex variables. Define
$$f_{\mathrm{symm}}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 
2^{-n}\sum_{\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n=\pm 1}
f(\varepsilon_1x_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n x_n),$$
i.e., the average of $f$ over all sign-changes of the arguments. I know that the resulting function (or a similarly defined measure, random variable, etc) is called "sign invariant", but what is the idempotent operator $f\mapsto f_{\mathrm{symm}}$ called?

Is there any general theory of this operator?  It is hard to search without a name.

Comment: I think this may be called a "polarization operator" --- see e.g., page 6 of Gurvits' paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510452v3

Comment: It's averaging over an action of a particular finite group, namely $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$. I think in some contexts the more general operation of averaging over an action of a finite group is called the Reynolds operator.